# Python's fromtimestamp returns inconsistent results on different machines

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have two computers, for the first one:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 7, 30)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1309846824)
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 5, 14, 20, 24)
```

for the second one:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 8, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1309846824)
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 5, 14, 20, 24)
```

How could they differ on '0' while agreeing on '1309846824'?

Comment: You should specify what the two computers are running in terms of OS as most probably this is some kind of difference in terms of how they increment the internal counter (leap seconds, timezone, for example).

Comment: the first one is linux (Linux newubuntu 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:09:38 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux), the second one is windows 7

Comment: windows is timezone naive, it has no history of when timezone rules have changed. I don't know why they have never improved this situation it's quite ridiculous

Comment: Aww, that means I was wrong. Oh well.

Comment: Indeed, this is timezone related - here in Santa Cruz California, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0) == datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 16, 0)

Comment: Could you find out at which date they start to differ? That might be interesting.

Comment: What timezone/locale are the machines set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the "asia" file that tzdata uses. On debian/ubuntu you can get this file by running the command `apt-get source tzdata`

```
...
# Zone  NAME            GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone Asia/Kuala_Lumpur  6:46:46 -       LMT     1901 Jan  1
                        6:55:25 -       SMT     1905 Jun  1 # Singapore M.T.
                        7:00    -       MALT    1933 Jan  1 # Malaya Time
                        7:00    0:20    MALST   1936 Jan  1
                        7:20    -       MALT    1941 Sep  1
                        7:30    -       MALT    1942 Feb 16
                        9:00    -       JST     1945 Sep 12
                        7:30    -       MALT    1982 Jan  1
                        8:00    -       MYT     # Malaysia Time
...
```

This describes how the timezone of Kuala Lumpur has changed since 1901. So in 1970 we see it was GMT+7.5 now it is GMT+8

Windows doesn't use any form of tzdata, so only knows the current offset